# OpenGL ES FBO Scaling

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fbo

This question is a follow up to
[the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052734/opengl-es-pixel-art-scaling) as recommended by [Matic Oblak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38056297/687976)

Once an FBO is setup and rendered to, how is the rendered image provided back to the default render buffer and displayed in a scaled version.

```
-(void)setupFBO {
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
}
```

Rendering to the FBO first:

```
-(void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect{

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glViewport (0, 0, 160, 144);
glClearColor (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glViewport(0, 0, 160, 144);

glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

If i uncomment the fbo binding, the square is displayed correctly - so i don't think its an issue with the VBO and VAO.

Attempt to display the result back to the main view scaled up to fit screen:

```
[((GLKView *) self.view) bindDrawable];
glViewport (0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
glClearColor (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//vb2 has the scaled vertex coordinates
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb2);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

//make sure we are not redrawing the same thing? the texture should be
//a colored cube based on what the fbo rendered.
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);

//create a buffer for the texture coordinates
//should be moved in setup phase, but left in for testing
glGenBuffers(1, &texBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*8, squareTex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
//bind to the fbo texture
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Some of the tutorials I've read and followed.

1. [OpenGL FBO Example](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples#Quick_example.2C_render_to_texture_.282D.29)
2. [Songho OGL FBO](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html)
3. [RTT](http://opengles2learning.blogspot.com/2014/02/render-to-texture-rtt.html)

Ultimately, i want an emulated GB screen of (160x144 pixels) to be displayed in the full width of the simulator (maintaining height ratio).

Im starting with a small square and trying to stretch it out to achieve the retro squared pixel effect.

Comment: What version of OpenGL ES are you using? You have calls that require at least ES 2.0, but also calls that are only valid in ES 1.x.

Comment: Es2, which ones are 1.x only? Most of the tutorials I found have the same calls.

Comment: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` is invalid in ES 2.0.

Comment: removed and added glActiveTexture instead.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a stretched effect all you need to do is draw a full screen rectangle with the texture. If no matrices are used you simply need to set vertex position data in range [-1,1] so for triangle strip:

```
{-1, -1,
  1, -1,
 -1,  1,
  1,  1}
```

The texture coordinates should be dependent on the original texture viewport ratio to texture size. For your example of `160x144` the nearest large enough texture size data would be `256x256` which results in `ratio = (160/256, 144/256)` so the coordinates are

```
{.0,       .0,
ratio.x,   .0,
.0,        ratio.y,
ratio.x,   ratio.y}
```

If this does not show a result you will need to find an issue which may be at any point. To begin with I would first try to draw this coordinates with a solid color to see if the rectangle is drawn full screen. If it is then the issue is most likely in the texture received from the FBO. If I may assume you are working with Xcode the best tool is to create a frame snapshot (a tool found on the bottom left part) which will show you all the calls and all the textures at any point of the frame. With it you may see if the texture is correctly draw to.

Do not forget to check for openGL errors (`glGetError`) and to check the status of the FBO buffer after attachments `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`.

This is a method from one of my projects which creates a FBO. It might be of some use to you.

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_renderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderBuffer);

    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8_OES, texture.textureWidth, texture.textureHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderBuffer);

    [texture bind];
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.textureID, 0);

    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &_bufferWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &_bufferHeight);

    [GLGlobalTools checkFramebufferStatus];
    [GLGlobalTools checkError];

    _bufferWidthf = _bufferWidth;
    _bufferHeightf = _bufferHeight;

    _surfaceWidth = (GLint)texture.imageWidth;
    _surfaceHeight = (GLint)texture.imageHeight;
```

Comment: so once rendering happens on the fbo, how is that then presented to the view on the iPhone? This code sample uses read pixels to create a texture and then uses that texture. http://www.dbfinteractive.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=bdaae040c3657115f2014ebfed001f0f&topic=3357.msg45040#msg45040

Comment: The same as any other texture. You use the texture that is attached to the FBO and draw it to the main buffer which is on the view already.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question - I do get a scaled square but the texture is still not rendered.

Comment: Is it not rendered to the main screen or is the texture itself empty? So if you clear a color to some non-zero value on the FBO do you see that color on the frame capture?

Comment: Assuming that i should be presented with a colored cube scaled up (which was rendered in FBO to texture) - i get a white cube with a different clear color. I think it has to do with the texture binding. The texture coordinates are correct I'm sure - i verified using ES1 and gl*Pointer calls.

Comment: just to be sure of the expected output - if i draw a coloured squared on the fbo with160x144 viewport with a texture bound, rebind that texture to a larger vertices then i should see that same colored square scaled up without passing color coordinates. right?

Comment: If the drawing to the texture is correct you might have an issue with drawing a texture to the main buffer. Are you using a correct shader that supports the textures? And yes about the output: Any scene you draw to the low resolution FBO that is redrawn to a high resolution buffer will look like a very zoomed image which can be a pixelated result. Using a correct combination of texture parameters and possibly some multisampling should give you the effect you are looking for.